# Hessian of a squared bilinear form

Tags: vectors, partial-derivative, vector-analysis, bilinear-form, hessian-matrix

I have to expand the function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ in Taylor series where
$$ f(x,y) = (x^TAy + B^Tx + C^Ty)^2$$

with $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$, $B\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $C\in\mathbb{R}^m$. I could rewrite it in two forms
$$\begin{aligned}
 f(x,y) &= x^T(Ay+B)(Ay+B)^Tx + 2x^T(Ay+B)C^Ty +y^TCC^Ty\\
 &= y^T(A^Tx+C)(A^Tx+C)^Ty + 2y^T(A^Tx+C)B^Tx +x^TBB^Tx
 \end{aligned}$$

To quickly check that
$$ \begin{aligned}
 \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} (x,y) &= 2(Ay+B)(Ay+B)^Tx + 2(Ay+B)C^Ty\\
 \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} (x,y) &= 2(A^Tx+C)(A^Tx+C)^Ty + 2(A^Tx+C)B^Tx 
 \end{aligned} $$
and
$$
 \begin{aligned}
 \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} (x,y) &= 2(Ay+B)(Ay+B)^T\\
 \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2} (x,y) &= 2(A^Tx+C)(A^Tx+C)^T
 \end{aligned}
$$

However, what about the cross term $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y}$? How to obtain it? The only thing I could think of was to calculate the gradient of each row of $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ with respect to $y$ and I obtained
$$\frac{\partial^2 f_i}{\partial x\partial y} (x,y) = 2(a_i^Tx^TA+A^Txa_i)y +2A^Txb_i+2B^Txa_i^T + 2(Ca_i+a_i^TC^T)y + 2Cb_i$$
where $a_i$ and $b_i$ are the $i$-th rows of $A$ and $B$. However, I tried to construct the matrix $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y}$ and I couldn't really find an single expression for it in terms of $A, B$ and $C$ in the end. Is it possible?

I would appreciate very much any suggestions. =)

Comment: Is $A$ assumed symmetric ?

Comment: No, and $A$ is not square ($x$ and $y$ are in different spaces)

Comment: 1) I wouldn't begin by expanding the square (because it is easier afterwards to consider $f$ as the composition of function $\varphi(x,y) = x^TAy + B^Tx + C^Ty$ with $(...)^2$ (the squaring function). 2) I would expand plainly $$\varphi(x+u,y+v) = (x+u)^TA(y+v) + B^T(x+u) + C^T(y+v)$$

Comment: Thanks, @JeanMarie, for your suggestion! The goal of expanding it is to find a local 2nd order approximation for $f(x,y)$. If I expand the inner function and square it later, I can't see how to get the linear and quadratic terms of the series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\def\m#1{\left[\begin{array}{c}#1\end{array}\right]}\def\p{{\partial}}\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}\def\hess#1#2#3{\frac{\p^2 #1}{\p #2\,\p #3^T}}$Combine
vector pairs into partitioned vectors
$$\eqalign{
w &= \pmatrix{x\\y} \qquad
h &= \pmatrix{b\\c} \qquad
w,h \in {\mathbb R}^{p} \\
}$$
where $p=m+n.\;$ Then consider the following partitioning of the identity matrix
$$\eqalign{
I_p = \m{I_n&0_{nm}\\0_{mn}&I_m} = \big[{E_1\;\big|\; E_2}\big]
}$$
The $E_k$ are matrix analogs of the standard basis vectors, which can be used either to *extract* components of a partitioned vector or matrix, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
x &= E_1^Tw \qquad y = E_2^Tw \qquad M_{ij} = E_i^TME_j \\
}$$
or to *construct* a partitioned vector or matrix from such components, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
w &= E_1x + E_2y \qquad M &= \sum_{i=1}^2 \sum_{i=j}^2 E_i M_{ij} E_j^T \qquad
I_p &= \left(E_1E_1^T + E_2E_2^T\right) \\
}$$
Applying this to the current problem
$$\eqalign{
x^TAy &= (E_1^Tw)^TA(E_2^Tw) = w^T(E_1AE_2^T)w = w^TMw \\
M &= \m{0_{nn}&A\\0_{mn}&0_{mm}}\\
}$$
Next, consider the following scalar function and its gradient and hessian.
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= x^TAy + b^Tx + c^Ty  \;=\; w^TMw + h^Tw \\
\grad{\phi}{w} &= 2Mw + h \\
\hess{\phi}{w}{w} &= 2M \\
}$$
Finally, write your function in terms of this function.

Then calculate its gradient and hessian with respect to $w$.
$$\eqalign{
f &= \phi^2 \\
\grad{f}{w} &= 2\phi\left(\grad{\phi}{w}\right) \\
\hess{f}{w}{w}
 &= 2\phi\left(\hess{\phi}{w}{w}\right)
 + 2\left(\grad{\phi}{w}\right)\left(\grad{\phi}{w}\right)^T \\
}$$
Look at the partitioned form and extract the desired component hessians, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
\hess{f}{w}{w} &= 
\m{ \hess{f}{x}{x} & \hess{f}{x}{y} \\ \hess{f}{y}{x} & \hess{f}{y}{y}} 
\quad\implies\quad
\hess{f}{x}{y} &= E_1^T \left(\hess{f}{w}{w}\right) E_2 \\\\
}$$

---

But it looks like you're after the Taylor series.

Expanding about the point $w_0$ yields
$$\eqalign{
f &= f(w) \\
f_0 &= f(w_0) \\
f &= f_0
  + \left(\grad{f}{w}\right)^T(w-w_0) 
  + \frac 12\,(w-w_0)^T\left(\hess{f}{w}{w}\right)(w-w_0) \\
}$$
which can be expressed much more concisely using *differentials*
$$\eqalign{
df &= (f-f_0) \\
dw &= (w-w_0) \\
df &= \left(\grad{f}{w}\right)^Tdw 
  + \frac 12\,dw^T\left(\hess{f}{w}{w}\right)dw \\
}$$
To break it into its block components, insert the identity matrix
$I_p$ between the various factors
$$\eqalign{
df &= \left(\grad{f}{w}\right)^T\left(E_1E_1^T + E_2E_2^T\right)dw \\ 
  &+\; \frac 12\,dw^T\left(E_1E_1^T + E_2E_2^T\right)\left(\hess{f}{w}{w}\right)\left(E_1E_1^T + E_2E_2^T\right)dw \\
}$$
and expand to get an expression in terms of the original $(x,y)$ variables 
$-$ I'll leave that exercise to you.

Comment: Wow, Thanks greg!  That's a very good idea :) 

I didn't know that the product rule could be used for hessians as in your before last equation. Could you refer to someplace where I could read more about it? 

All the best!

Comment: @LucasEgidio The standard text is probably Magnus and Neudecker's _Matrix Differential Calculus_